# Yii2 Migration Not Update Database

Tags: php, database, yii, yii2, migration

the system does not see my migration file. I created new migrate and
`php yii migrate --migratePath=@common/migrations/` then no new rule. Can anyone figure it out?

Comment: It is `migrationPath`, not `migratePath`.

Comment: yes, i typed wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this to you console/config/main.php(advanced)

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'migrate' => [
        'class' => \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::class,
        'migrationPath' => [
            '@common/migrations',
        ],
    ],
],
```

[Yii Migration Namespace](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations#namespaced-migrations)

Then you have to call

```
yii migrate/up
```

Comment: i change my migration name type. it was m200826_1543_post.php so i turned it m200826_00001_post.php and its work. Thank you for your solution.